# ISCSI - how to connect only in one target session?

Tags: linux, iscsi, targetcli

I have created a lab for databases, and when I am discovering the targets, it show two sessions (1,2):

```
10.0.0.17:3260,1 iqn.2003-01.org.linux-iscsi.san.x8664:sn.b5aad37c0404
10.0.0.17:3260,2 iqn.2003-01.org.linux-iscsi.san.x8664:sn.b5aad37c0404
```

How can I connect to only one session? I guess those sessions are for multiple paths, right? since is a lab, I don't have a multipath configured, not needed.

I have tried something like it (,1 at the end):

```
iscsiadm --mode node --targetname iqn.2003-01.org.linux-iscsi.san.x8664:sn.b5aad37c0404 --portal 10.0.0.17:3260,1 --login
```

But the two sessions are connected.

I' am using targetcli in a linux machine to simulate it.

If possible, I can disable on target server side as well.